# I can't get to work this Instances of Show / Functor for my Forest datatype

Tags: haskell, tree, instance, show, functor

I've started programming in haskell like 2 months ago, im fairly new so don't expect me to be some top tier expect at monads or whatever please. I have tried in so many ways to get this Forest dataType be instance of functor and show, but i really don't know how to solve the conflicts that the compiler is giving to me. Such as:

```
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘Tree’
    Perhaps you meant ‘True’ (imported from Prelude)
   |
15 |     show ((Tree a) : (Forest s) ) = "[" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show s ++ "]"
   |            ^^^^

exercici3.hs:15:23: error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Forest’
   |
15 |     show ((Tree a) : (Forest s) ) = "[" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show s ++ "]"
   |                       ^^^^^^

exercici3.hs:19:12: error:
    Not in scope: data constructor ‘Tree’
    Perhaps you meant ‘True’ (imported from Prelude)
   |
19 |     fmap ((Tree a) : (Forest s)) = [f a] ++ (fmap f s)
   |            ^^^^

exercici3.hs:19:23: error: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Forest’
   |
19 |     fmap ((Tree a) : (Forest s)) = [f a] ++ (fmap f s)
   |                       ^^^^^^
```

This is the font code of the classes. I've been thinking for a long time and i can't find a resonable solution, all help is welcome , thank you!

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
data Forest a = Nil  | Cons (Tree a) (Forest a)

instance Show a => Show (Tree a) where
    show Empty = "()"
    show (Node b (xl) (xr)) = "(" ++ show xl ++ "," ++ (show b) ++  "," ++ show xr ++ ")"

instance Functor (Tree ) where
    fmap  f Empty  = Empty
    fmap  f (Node a (xl) (xr)) = Node (f a) (fmap f xl) (fmap f xr)

instance Show a => Show (Forest a) where
    show Nil = []
    show ((Tree a) : (Forest s) ) = "[" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show s ++ "]"

instance Functor (Forest) where
    fmap f Nil = []
    fmap ((Tree a) : (Forest s)) = [f a] ++ (fmap f s)
```

Just to be clear, the Tree datatype works just fine, its just the syntactic part of the forest that doesnt seem to work at all.

Answer (score 4):

The data constructor is `Cons`, not `(:)`. Then you use for example `x` and `xs` as variables, where `x` has type `Tree a`, and `xs` has type `Forest a`:

```
instance Show a => Show (Forest a) where
    show Nil = ""
    show (Cons x xs) = "[" ++ show x ++ "," ++ show xs ++ "]"

instance Functor Forest where
    fmap f Nil = Nil
    fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (fmap f x) (fmap f xs)
```

That being said, I don't see much reasons to define a data type `Forest` here, you can define this as:

```
type Forest a = [Tree a]
```

Comment: ohhhh thank you, my professor hasn't told me about this. Anyway still doesn't work at all, i've changed the fmap f Nil = Nil, because [] was giving me some compiler warnings, but i still got an error at this line    fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)

Comment: even if i add the TYPE option i still get an error

exercici3.hs:22:19: error:
    • Could not deduce (Num (Tree a)) arising from a use of ‘*’
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   doubleF :: forall a. Num a => Forest a -> Forest a
        at exercici3.hs:21:1-40
    • In the first argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘(* 2)’
      In the expression: fmap (* 2) x
      In an equation for ‘doubleF’: doubleF x = fmap (* 2) x

The error is from another function that i use, but i see the fmap isn't working as it should or something

Comment: The line should be `fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (fmap f x) (fmap f xs)`. You should read the type errors for the functor implementation, it will help you figure out the error.